# Get byte array from html file

Tags: jquery, html

I was just wondering about how could i possible get bytes array from an html input file.

The code is as below:

```
  <script type ="text/javascript">            

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#cmdUpload').click(function() {

                uploadFile();

            });

            function uploadFile() {

                var file = $("#objFile")[0].files[0];




            }
        });
    </script>
      <body>
     <input type ="file" id="objFile" size="50" /><br/><br/>
     <input type ="button" id="cmdUpload"  value="Upload"/>
    </body>
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Can you also provide html here ?

Comment: <input type ="file" id="objFile" size="50" /><br/><br/>
    
    <input type ="button" id="cmdUpload"  value="Upload"/>

Comment: Good and where you want to call uploadFile function? means on objfile click or cmdUpload click ?

Comment: <script type ="text/javascript">            

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#cmdUpload').click(function() {

                    uploadFile();

                });

                function uploadFile() {

                    var file = $("#objFile")[0].files[0];

                  
                    
    
                }
            });
        </script>

Answer (score 3):

This is the sample code which is returning Bytes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cmdUpload').click(function() {
    uploadFile();
  });

});

function uploadFile() {
  var input = document.getElementById('objFile');
  // var file = $("#objFile")[0].files[0];
  var file = input.files[0];
  fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = receivedText;
  //fr.readAsText(file);
  fr.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function receivedText() {
  var b64Data = fr.result.split(',');
  var contentType = 'image/jpeg';
  //document.getElementById('editor').appendChild(document.createTextNode(fr.result))
  var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data[1]);
  var byteNumbers = Array.prototype.map.call(byteCharacters,
    charCodeFromCharacter);
  var uint8Data = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
  var blob = b64toBlob(b64Data[1], contentType);
  var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
}

function charCodeFromCharacter(c) {
  return c.charCodeAt(0);
}

function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
  contentType = contentType || '';
  sliceSize = sliceSize || 1024;
  var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
  var byteArrays = [];

  for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
    var byteNumbers = Array.prototype.map.call(slice, charCodeFromCharacter);
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
    alert(byteArray[i]);
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="file" id="objFile" size="50" /><br />
  <br />
  <input type="button" id="cmdUpload" value="Upload" />
  <div id="editor"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help you. please let me know for further assistance.

Comment: i m trying it out for the moment and let you know afterwards.

Comment: the last thing is Can i include multiple file types such gif , png etx

Comment: Yes you can do it by splitting b64Data[0] further. Please check b64Data[0] output and get value according to your requirement.